# Determine if download object is an HTML redirection page - stop downloading before the page loads

Tags: ios, objective-c, download

When I try to download a file with [AFDownloadRequestOperation](https://github.com/steipete/AFDownloadRequestOperation) from a URL, the Wi-fi router turns off internet connection and redirects me to an authorization page. The download process does not stop during this redirection and I get an HTML redirection page instead of a file that was supposed to be downloaded. It tells me that it's *okay* and  that the file is downloaded.

How can I determine that a download object is an html redirection page and stop downloading it before I get that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSURLConnection (the underlying framework class) does support this sort of notificationvia:

`- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;`

=> AFNetworking exposes this via block that is to be called when a redirect happens:

`@property (readwrite, nonatomic, copy) AFURLConnectionOperationRedirectResponseBlock redirectResponse;`

Comment: I found in AFNetworking - (void)setRedirectResponseBlock:(NSURLRequest * (^)(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *redirectResponse))block;

Comment: edited my answer, I had looked into an old version of AFNetworking I use for my project. Nowadays it is even exposed